# automatically place downloaded files in folder bsed on downloads extension suffix

Tags: vb.net, browser, file-extension

I’m making a simple web browser for work eeh, what I’d like to know is if its possible to save a file of a particular extension to a particular file.

I currently use google chrome when downloading a file it places this (regardless of extension) in a downloads folder without asking where I ant to download this too.

I want to achieve the same except that downloads with the extension .dwg are placed automatically in a folder named DWG DOWNLOADS…

How to achieve this in vb.net?

Comment: take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773866/download-file-and-automatically-save-it-to-folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any browser you have a config section.

In Firefox you have `browser.download.useDownloadDir;true` and `browser.download.folderList;1`

you can add your own config to allow different saved folder paths and dynamically modify them depending on the extension of the file you uploaded.

See a complete list of the web browser config with about:config in address bar.

Comment: im not sure if you build your own vb.net browser (which implements IE).

Answer (score 0):

Not real sure what you are asking, but if you are actually making a web browser just check the extension of the file you are requesting to download. If the extension is ".dwg" then save the file to the folder you want.

If you are wanting to automatically move Google Chrome downloads to a different directory, you can use a `FileSystemWatcher` to monitor for new files in Chrome's download directory and move them to another folder based on each file's extension.