# Automatic download and install a exe file to the client system .net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am currently working on asp.net,c# and javascript. I have tried to automatic download and install from server to client system.

I a partially done by using Webclient . I used this way : [Download file and automatically save it to folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773866/download-file-and-automatically-save-it-to-folder)

But it's works only downloaded, But i don't know how to install this automatically?

Let me know i want to do, like the following requirements.

**I have one exe file in my server, But i need to install this exe to client (local) system.**

> - Automatically install and run the exe to local server by using browser download popup details.(ex: IE and Firefox) by using c# or JavaScript.
> - And I want to where is the file was downloaded and need to display that path to user like the exe was download path"@C/FolderName/Filename". using c# or javascript.

Is it possible? Please advise me.

below is some ideas of mine , but i don't know is it possible, So i open suggestion

> - The webclient was downloaded file to the client system, Can any possible way to download exe and get tha path for where it download?
> - download file with developer defined path?
> - Dynamically create folder in local system and download the exe in tht dynamic path?

Comment: No its not. If you could install applications on a users PC (without an exploit) it would be a gigantic security issue.

Comment: Well it depends on a lots of factors. I recently had make a little library which allows me to download and run the latest version of MongoDB. At first, I clearly though it wouldn't be possible to run this on a production server, but I was wrong. 

So, yeah you're able to run executable files, but you won't have any UI. Try using the Process class. Oh and, don't forget the IIS user in which your ASP.NET application is running. It is with these users rights you will be able to mess something with the executable file (that's what I guess there, never tried).

Comment: @SimonWhitehead. The webclient was downloaded file to the client system, Can any possible way to download exe and where it download? or  download file with manual path? or dynamically create folder in local system and download the exe in tht dynamic path?

Comment: You are incorrect. The WebClient has downloaded it **to the server**. There is no way to forcefully download and install an application on a **client** PC with ASP.NET.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, Are you sure? Is the Webclient has download only server?

Comment: Yes. The WebClient is a server-side object. It doesnt magically transfer files to clients. It downloads them locally.